# java for each loop expects object as type while it contains an integer array

Tags: java, arraylist

I got a beginner's Java question.

I am filling an `ArrayList` like this:

```
   private ArrayList getDuplicatesIndexes(char[] letters) {
        ArrayList<int[]> duplicatesIndexes = new ArrayList<int[]>();

        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++ ) {

            for(int j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("compare this");
                System.out.println(letters[i]);
                System.out.println("with this:");
                System.out.println(letters[j]);
                if(letters[i] == letters[j] && i != j) {
                    System.out.println("match!");
                    int[] indexes = new int[2];
                    indexes[0] = i;
                    indexes[1] = j;
                    duplicatesIndexes.add(indexes);
                }
            }
        }

        return duplicatesIndexes;
    }
```

I want to loop through it like this:

```
private void checkForSingularLetters(ArrayList duplicatesIndexes, char[] letters) {
        for(int[] indexes : duplicatesIndexes ){
            System.out.println(indexes[0]);
            ...
        }


}
```

I cant wrap my mind about why the foreach loop is expecting an object while im sure its filled with `int[]`

Maybe someone could explain it to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the raw form of `ArrayList` in your method `checkForSingularLetters`, so that means that `Object` is expected when iterating.  After all, a raw `ArrayList` could contain anything.

Use the generic form of `ArrayList` in your method parameter:

```
private void checkForSingularLetters(ArrayList<int[]> duplicatesIndexes, char[] letters)
```

Comment: So basically I did not explicitly tell the parameter ArrayList class that I want to have an Integer array as type? And that causes to interpret is as 'some kind' of object?

Comment: Yes, when using the raw form of a class, the signatures of all methods  become their own type erasures, which means that instead of an `int[]` being returned by the iterator, an `Object` is returned.

Comment: Great, thanks for your comment and answer, will approve it asap. Lastly, can anyone point me to some useful articles with more in depth stuff about generics?

Comment: Search your favorite search engine for "java generics tutorial".

Comment: .. already did that, wondered if someone had a nice reccomendation. But never mind.

Answer (score 2):

You have an untyped `ArrayList` which contains `Object` by default - try extending the method signature by `ArrayList<int[]> duplicatesIndexes`,

Answer (score 1):

In the method name, you have a raw ArrayList. Hence it expects the items inside it to be of type objects. Try using ArrayList duplicateIndexes inside the method signature and it should solve your problem.